# DÚVIDA EM UM SELECT - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-select

Tenho basicamente esse relacionamentos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de pegar o valor do atributo "im_fab_modelo" da tabela "tblImpressora" a parti do código do atributo "is_cod_impressora" da tabela "tblImpressoraSetor", alguém pode me ajudar?

Por enquanto tenho esse select:

```
SELECT tblTonerEntSai.es_cod_toner_ent_sai, tblToner.tn_modelo, tblSetor.st_nome,

tblImpressoraSetor.is_cod_impressora, tblImpressoraSetor.is_siap, tblTonerEntSai.es_entrada_saida, 

tblTonerEntSai.es_quantidade, tblTonerEntSai.es_solicitante FROM tblTonerEntSai 

INNER JOIN tblToner ON (tblTonerEntSai.es_cod_toner = tblToner.tn_cod_toner)

INNER JOIN tblSetor ON (tblTonerEntSai.es_cod_setor = tblSetor.st_cod_setor)

INNER JOIN tblImpressoraSetor ON (tblTonerEntSai.es_cod_impressora_setor = tblImpressoraSetor.is_cod_imp_setor)
```

O mesmo me retorna os seguintes dados:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>es_cod_toner_ent_sai</th>
    <th>tn_modelo</th>
    <th>st_nome</th>
    <th>is_cod_impressora</th>
    <th>is_siap</th>
    <th>es_entrada_saida</th>
    <th>es_quantidade</th>
    <th>es_solicitante</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>MODELO DA IMPRESSORA<br></td>
    <td>NOME DO SETOR<br></td>
    <td>3<br></td>
    <td>0000.0000<br></td>
    <td>09/07/2016<br></td>
    <td>4<br></td>
    <td>DEIVIDY<br></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Observação: não quero criar um novo relacionamento.

Comment: Eu acho que você poderia detalhar mais, to tentando entender aqui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se é o que eu entendi, é só você fazer:

```
SELECT tblImpressora.im_fab_modelo as Modelo
FROM tblImpressoraSetor
INNER JOIN tblImpressora ON (tblImpressora.im_cod_ = tblImpressoraSetor.is_cod_impressora);
```

Ou:

```
SELECT tblImpressora.im_fab_modelo as Modelo
FROM tblImpressoraSetor, tblImpressora
WHERE tblImpressora.im_cod_impressora = tblImpressoraSetor.is_cod_impressora;
```

Obviamente que fazendo isso seguindo as restrições de integridade referencial que você **deve** ter feito. Pelo que eu entendi do seu problema, eu acho que é isso aí, bem simples.

**EDIÇÃO:**
Entendi, bom é só você acrescentar mais uma cláusula `JOIN`:

```
SELECT tblTonerEntSai.es_cod_toner_ent_sai, tblToner.tn_modelo, tblSetor.st_nome,
tblImpressoraSetor.is_cod_impressora, tblImpressoraSetor.is_siap, tblTonerEntSai.es_entrada_saida, 
tblTonerEntSai.es_quantidade, tblTonerEntSai.es_solicitante, tblImpressora.im_fab_modelo

FROM tblTonerEntSai 
    INNER JOIN tblToner ON (tblTonerEntSai.es_cod_toner = tblToner.tn_cod_toner)
    INNER JOIN tblSetor ON (tblTonerEntSai.es_cod_setor = tblSetor.st_cod_setor)
    INNER JOIN tblImpressoraSetor ON (tblTonerEntSai.es_cod_impressora_setor = tblImpressoraSetor.is_cod_imp_setor)
    INNER JOIN tblImpressora ON (tblImpressoraSetor.is_cod_impressora = tblImpressora.im_cod_impressora);
```

Eu acho que isso funciona, você está fazendo **JOIN** entre as tabelas então se não me engano eu posso referenciar `tblImpressoraSetor.is_cod_impressora` tranquilamente que não tem problema, afinal você está colocando tudo na mesma tabela de resultado. O problema é se você poder aceitar valores nulos em alguns dos lados, aí você teria que usar `LEFT JOIN` ou `RIGHT JOIN`, ou outras operações. Mas faz o teste aí, deve dar. 
**[DICA]**
Tenta separar essa consulta, ela poderia ser dividida, que seria mais legível e talvez até mais rápida.

Comment: Eu acrescentei o que você "estava" querendo, tá entre aspas porque não entendi direito o seu problema. Faz o teste aí e vê se assim também dá certo. Eu fiz a primeira resposta daquela forma porque fica muito mais simples e desacoplado as coisas, eu acho melhor. O ``as Modelo`` é pra renomear o atributo ``tblImpressora.im_fab_modelo`` na tabela resultante, que convenhamos, fica bem mais legível.